# Сполучник якби і однозвучне словосполучення

Tags: правопис

Любі друзі, допоможіть, будь ласка, навчитись розрізняти сполучник **якби** і однозвучне з ним сполучення прислівника з часткою. Це важливо для правильного написання:сполучник пишеться одним словом, на відміну від сполучення слів. Приклад сполучника у реченні:

1. **Якби** я була зіркою в небі,   я б не знала ні туги, ні жалю (Леся
   Українка).

А це поєднання прислівника з часткою:

2. **Як би** я тепер хотіла у мале човенце сісти і далеко на схід сонця
   золотим шляхом поплисти! (Леся Українка).

В «Українському правописі» такої інформації не подано. З Вікіпедії я дізналась, що це складний похідний сполучник, не має лексичного значення і не виконує у реченні граматичну роль. Як я зрозуміла, - до нього **не можна поставити питання**, як до прислівника, та він **не є членом речення**. До прислівника із другого прикладу можна поставити питання: **якою мірою**? І він виступає у реченні **обставиною**. Поставити запитання складно.
Чи є ще способи вирізнити сполучник?

Comment: Поки не можу зформолӱвати, хоча наче розуміӱ відмінність. Накидаӱ реченнӓ длӓ прикладу і грубі порівнӓннӓ: _ӓк би панї відповіла ≈ хоч би панї відповіла • ӓкби панї віповіла ≈ ось би панї відповіла_; а тут легше: _ӓк би панї відповіла, ӓкби знала відповідї?_ Також зазначу ріжницӱ наголосів, [в правописї](http://litopys.org.ua/pravopys/rozdil1.htm#par32) те ё: _ӓ́к би_ • _ӓкби́_.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[WebPen: Правопис сполучників](http://webpen.com.ua/pages/Morphology_constant_leng_parts/conjunction_spelling.html)

> #### Розрізнення сполучників та інших частин мови
>
> Сполучники можна замінити іншими синонімічними сполучниками: *таж* — *адже*, *теж* — *також*, *тож* — *тому*, ***якби*** — ***коли б***, якже — якщо, якщо — коли, щоб — аби, проте — однак, зате — але, притому — до того ж, причому — і то.
>
> Однозвучні ж поєднання інших частин мови замінити сполучниками не можна.
>
> Сполучники членами речення не бувають і не відповідають на питання (на питання може відповідати все підрядне речення, а не сам сполучник).
>
> Однозвучні ж поєднання слів є членами речення і відповідають на питання в реченні: *яка?* — *та ж*; *яке?* — *те ж*; *що?* — *то ж*; ***як?*** ***яким способом?*** — ***як би***, *як же*; *що?* — *що б*; *про що?* *про яке?* — *про те*; *за що?* *за яке?* — *за те*; *при чому?* — *при тому*, *при чому*.
>
> Порівняйте:
>
> *Я мусив заховатися від вас, **Щоб** ви не бачили мого ридання, Не знали глибини моїх ураз* (Данте Аліг’єрі). *А вона на **що б** не дивилася, де б не гуляла — всюди ввижаються їй дрімучі волинські праліси* (М. Олійник);
>
> ***Якби́*** мені крила, крила соколинії, полетіла б я за милим, за дружиною (Т. Шевченко). ***Я́к би*** там не було, а література — моя професія (Леся Українка);
>
> *На гору доступитися нелегко, **зате** з гори зручніше боронитись* (Леся Українка). *Повинна дякувати мамі **за те**, що будила рано, навчила всього робити;*
>
> *Смерть — то короткий подих, мить остання, **Якщо́** вона закон — не покарання.* (Ф. де Кеведо). *Я́к що трапиться, ні на кого не нарікай*.

Як видно, тут також увага на наголоси. Те саме зауважує [правопис](http://litopys.org.ua/pravopys/rozdil1.htm#par32)

> #### § 32. Сполучники
>
> Сполучники **якби́**, **якщо́** можна відрізнити від однозвучного з ними прислівника як із часткою би та займенником що за допомогою контексту, бо на прислівник **як** завжди падає логічний наголос. Пор.:
>
> > ***Якби*** тут був мій товариш!; але: ***Як би*** краще виконати завдання!
> >
> > ***Якщо*** хочеш, допоможу тобі; але: ***Як що*** трапиться, нарікай на себе.